# How can i implement Native facebook login button widget in cordova

Tags: cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, ngcordova

I am working on a cordova android application. I want to implement facebook native login widget for login in facebook like native android widget

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android:id="@+id/login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Please give your valueable suggestions

Comment: May be you need to create copy image and setup that image in your div class as i know you can't setup native widget directly in cordova.